# Command running as root but not with sudo

Tags: linux, centos, samba, centos-7

I'm currently configuring a Samba 4 DC on CentOS 7.

As myself, `samba-tool` runs fine but when I run `sudo samba-tool` I get `command not found`.

`samba-tool` is located in `/usr/local/samba/bin`. I've added the directory to the PATH for both myself and root.

As myself, `env | ^PATH=` correctly includes the above directory. However, `sudo env | ^PATH=` shows only `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin`.

Switching now to the root user. `env | ^PATH=` returns `PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/samba/bin:/usr/local/samba/sbin` and `samba-tool` runs just fine.

It was my intuition that sudo perfectly mirrored the root user, which I guess is not the case. A fix and hopefully an explanation is highly appreciated.

Comment: Try using 'su', then execute the command without 'sudo'.

Comment: @Thijs365 I don't understand, do you mean switch into root and run the command? I'm already aware that that works.

Comment: Okay. Are you sure you have sudo installed?

Comment: @Thijs365 Yes. Sudo works as expected for its env path above.

Comment: Okay. I won't say anything anymore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It may be your `sudo` uses `PATH` defined in `/etc/sudoers` file, not the root's `PATH`. Check `man 5 sudoers`, look for the `secure_path` option.

You may also read
*[How to make `sudo` preserve $PATH?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/83191/108618)*

Hint: use `visudo` to edit `/etc/sudoers`. The tool does some sanity check and may save you from the situation when you lose sudo access due to invalid edit.